# how to run autohotkey code sequential manner in c#?

Tags: c#, autohotkey

i using autohotkey.dll in c#.

i want to run sequential manner each step but

for instance i have following code and

when reach Sleep,5000 it need to wait 5sec

but it just not wait 5sec it just execute Messagebox.show dialog .

how can i run each step ?

thanks for help

```
string scriptContent = @"
WinActivate, chrome
sleep, 5000
"
CoCOMServer ahkThread = new CoCOMServer();
ahkThread.ahktextdll(scriptContent);
MessageBox.Show("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the ahk script to exit:

```
string scriptContent = @"
WinActivate, chrome
sleep, 5000
"
CoCOMServer ahkThread = new CoCOMServer();
ahkThread.ahktextdll(scriptContent);

while (ahkThread.ahkReady() != 0) // will check evey 100 millisecond if the script still runs
    Thread.Sleep(100); 

MessageBox.Show("hello");
```